# how to remove a file in filestack-react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm new in reactjs and filestack api and im using its filestack-react 
 i was wondering how do i delete a file? the mode is remove but it keep on saying handle is required i already know that but i don't know how to send it using this plugin here's my code

```
  <img src={this.state.url} />
  <ReactFilestack
      apikey={this.state.apikey}
      buttonText="X"
      mode="remove"
      options={this.state.handle}
      handle={this.state.handle}
      onSuccess={this.removeFile}  
 />
```

How do i Delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filestack-React looks for a handle string to be passed into the remove function here. You should have security passed in to remove files as well.

I'm not sure where in your code you are specifying the handle, but perhaps this page here will help you understand what the remove function is looking for.

https://www.filestack.com/docs/javascript-api/remove-v3